# Weird background when using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

When I use the dialog of jQuery UI I get a weird background picture/pixel

Just wondering if you also get it to in your computer?

> jsbin.com/yikufeyixe/edit?html,css,js,output

Thank you!

The code don't work in stackoverflow's snippet but it works at jsbin

[image]

Comment: What browser and OS are you testing on?

Comment: chrome win 10...'

Comment: FireFox 56, 32-bit, Lubuntu, unable to replicate. I suspect this is a redraw issue. May want to check if this happens when you have "lots" of things open or with only Chrome. Try alternate browsers. Check for Windows updates, graphics driver updates, or known issues in Win 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is what I see]

This is what I see using the jsbin link you provided. It looks fine to me.